# Execution of sql query takes a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this problem with my query that it is really slow. I am using MSSQL server 2008 and have 3 DB with hundreds of sample data in it. The query will return a name and value and a computed percentage based on the 3 DBs. But the query I have will take almost 10mins to execute which is really a long time to take. I am still learning SQL and still not that good so I think the query I have is not using the best practice and not organized. Can anybody point to me where or how I can improve my query to run faster?

```
SELECT data.Ret,
    case 
        when @group_by= 'site' OR (@group_by='attribute' AND @attribute_id = '5') and (data.rowid % 50) = 0 then (data.rowid / 50)-1
        when @group_by= 'site' OR (@group_by='attribute' AND @attribute_id = '5') then (data.rowid / 50) 
        else 0 end as batchStore
        ,data.MajorName,data.MinorName,data.MajorVal,data.MinorVal,data.Version
        ,data.A_Percent,data.T_Percent,data.F_Percent
from 
(
    SELECT report.Ret,
        CASE when @group_by= 'site' OR (@group_by='attribute' AND @attribute_id = '5') 
        then row_number() over (PARTITION BY report.Ret,report.Version order by report.Ret, report.MajorName)
        else 0 end  as rowid
        ,report.MajorName,report.MinorName,report.MajorVal,report.MinorVal,report.Version
        ,report.GTotal_A,report.GTotal_T,report.GTotal_F
        ,ISNULL(sum(report.Abn) / NULLIF(cast(report.GTotal_A as decimal),0),0) * 100 as A_Percent
        ,ISNULL(sum(report.Trn) / NULLIF(cast(report.GTotal_T as decimal),0),0) * 100 as T_Percent
        ,ISNULL(sum(report.Fld)/ NULLIF(cast(report.GTotal_F as decimal),0) * 100,0) as F_Percent
    From 
    (
        Select
            CASE @group_by
            WHEN 'object' THEN csl.s_name
            WHEN 'site' THEN csl.s_name
            WHEN 'year' THEN CAST(YEAR(dy.Day_Stamp) AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN 'attribute' THEN CAST(coalesce(attrib.AttributeName,'') AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE ''
            END as MajorName,
            CASE @group_by
            WHEN 'object' THEN l.l_name
            WHEN 'site' THEN ''
            WHEN 'attribute' THEN CAST(coalesce(attrib.AttributeName,'') AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE ''
            END as MinorName,
            CASE @group_by
            WHEN 'object' THEN csl.s_name
            WHEN 'site' THEN csl.s_name
            WHEN 'year' THEN CAST(YEAR(dy.Day_Stamp) AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN 'attribute' THEN CAST(coalesce(attrib.AttributeValue,'') AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE ''
            END as MajorVal,
            CASE @group_by
            WHEN 'object' THEN l.l_name
            WHEN 'site' THEN ''
            WHEN 'attribute' THEN CAST(coalesce(attrib.AttributeValue,'') AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE ''
            END as MinorVal,
            csl.Cust_Name as Ret,l.SWVersion as Version
            ,d.Abn,d.Trn,d.Fld,data.GTotal_A ,data.GTotal_T,data.GTotal_F
        From db_mon.dbo.CustSL csl
            join db_tax.dbo.vwLane l 
                on (l.externalid = csl.custsl_id)
            join db_mon.dbo.DaySummary dy 
                on (dy.Str = csl.s_name and dy.Lne = csl.l_name and year(dy.day_stamp) = year(@time_start_date) and year(dy.day_stamp) =year(@time_end_date))
            Left Outer Join
                (
                    Select a.id As AttributeId, a.attribute_name As AttributeName,
                    (Case When a.attribute_value_type = 'string' Then ea.string_value
                        Else (Case When a.attribute_value_type = 'integer' Then cast(ea.integer_value as nvarchar(100))
                            Else (Case When a.attribute_value_type = 'date' Then cast(ea.date_value as nvarchar(100))
                                Else (Case When a.attribute_value_type = 'boolean' Then cast(ea.boolean_value as nvarchar(100))
                                    Else (Case When a.attribute_value_type = 'entity' Then cast(ea.ref_entity_id as nvarchar(100)) Else null End)
                                    End)
                                End)
                            End)
                        End) As AttributeValue,
                     e.id As EntityId
                     From db_tax.dbo.entity_type et
                     Inner Join db_tax.dbo.entity As e on et.id = e.entity_type_id
                     Inner Join db_tax.dbo.entity_attribute As ea on e.id = ea.entity_id
                     Inner Join db_tax.dbo.attribute As a on ea.attribute_id = a.id
                     WHERE et.entity_type_name in ('Sticker','Label') And
                     a.id = (case WHEN @attribute_id = '' then 1 else cast(@attribute_id as int) end)
                ) AS attrib 
                    On attrib.EntityId = l.L_Id
             inner join db_mon.dbo.DaySummary d 
                on (csl.Cust_Name = d.Ret and csl.s_name = d.stckr and csl.l_name = d.label and l.SWVersion = d.Version)
             join ( 
                SELECT Ret,version,sum(Abn) as GTotal_A,sum(Trn) as GTotal_T,sum(Fld) as GTotal_F
                from db_mon.dbo.DaySummary
                where day_stamp >= @time_start_date and day_stamp <=@time_end_date
                GROUP BY Ret,version   
             ) data 
                on (d.Ret = data.Ret and l.SWVersion = data.Version)
        WHERE (CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,l.S_Id) + ',','xxx,' + @entities + ',xxx')>0 OR CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,l.L_Id) + ',','xxx,' + @entities + ',xxx')>0)
        and d.day_stamp >= @time_start_date 
        and d.day_stamp <=@time_end_date
    ) As report
Group By report.Ret,report.Version,report.MajorName,report.MinorName,report.MajorVal,report.MinorVal
,report.GTotal_A,report.GTotal_T,report.GTotal_F
)data
order By data.Ret,data.Version,batchStore,data.MajorName,data.MinorName,data.MajorVal,data.MinorVal
```

Does using a lot of join causes the slow execution?

Comment: BTW hundrets of data is nothing. millions of data is normal.

Comment: That's a very big fat query. It will be difficult to answer, there are hundreds of possibility of why this is slow. You have to reduce the size of the query until you find where is the bottleneck.

Comment: you can look at the execution plan to seee the time consumers

Comment: to help you we would need table structures, example data, expected output and what you actually want to achieve with that query.

Comment: There are 4 queries combined to make this. Tested each one of it and it runs fast but when all 4 are combined it would be really slow. I think it might be on the way im using the "join" that is causing this...

Comment: Check that your primary keys are indexed - they will be if you have the constraints set, and also that your foreign key fields are indexed.

Comment: When you have a SQL query which is so complex that it doesn't fit on one screen, you should rather write a reporting program in a general purpose programming language which fetches the data with one or more simple SQL queries and then does the data processing.

Answer (score 0):

SUB Select queries will always be slower then proper joins.

You are running 3 sub selects deep. This is going to impact your performance regardless of changing indexes etc.

You need to rewrite the whole thing to stop using sub selects.